# how to start search at specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hi one of the line is looking for the column for specific city

```
Count = WorksheetFunction.Match("city", Rows("2:2"), 0)
```

I tried to modify it, so it would look up specific state as well by referring to row 1
 I was hoping that once it finds the column. it would just start the search at Column
 But it looks like the macro is still searching from column A, instead of the State Column.

```
Column= WorksheetFunction.Match("state", Rows("1:1"), 0)
 Cells(1, Column).Activate

 Count = WorksheetFunction.Match("city", Rows("2:2"), 0)
```

is the second row wrong maybe?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that - I have an if statement right above the code that activate the worksheet I need. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    kolumn = WorksheetFunction.Match("state", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    kount = WorksheetFunction.Match("city", Range(Cells(2, kolumn), Cells(2, Columns.Count)), 0)
    MsgBox kolumn & vbCrLf & kount + kolumn - 1
End Sub
```

[image]

The *city* after the *state* is found.

Comment: hello! when i tried to run your code, it says "unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class". Thanks !

Comment: oh this must be case sensitive. it works when i use lower case c. thanks !

Comment: We can also just use"MsgBox kount + kolumn - 1" to show "7", right? Could you explain your line of code and why it's better? Thanks !